# dask dataframe error for column having value : 2023-01-03T06:58:46.360000+00:19207, while writing into csv

Tags: python, dataframe, dask

My csv file has column "Completion Date" which has values in format

'2023-01-03**T**06:58:46.360000+00:00'

I think it is getting stuck because it has "T" in between the datetime stamp

```py
import dask.dataframe as daskDataFrame

colsToKeep=['Email','Content Title','Completion Date','Status']

infile="E://t//1.csv"
outfile="E://t//2.csv"

dataSet = daskDataFrame.read_csv(infile, usecols=colsToKeep)
#print(dataSet.dtypes)
dataSet.to_csv(outfile)
```

I have a csv file with 26 columns, I just want to keep 4 out of these 26 columns.
So I was reading the csv and then copying 4 columns into new csv file.

But it is failing while saving "Completed Date" column values.

ERROR:

[**ValueError**: could not convert string to float: '2023-01-03**T**06:58:46.360000+00:00'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmiNB.jpg)

[**ValueError**: could not convert string to float: '2023-01-03**T**06:58:46.360000+00:00'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLjTq.png)

Comment: You write about dask dataframe error, but you didn't mentioned what error is it. Please provide full error message.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that `dask` is trying to convert them to `float`, but failed. You can specify it as type `object` (which is string in `pandas`) like this:

```py
dataSet = daskDataFrame.read_csv(infile, usecols=colsToKeep, dtype='object')
```